# Porque os pseudo-elementos ::after e ::before não funcionam em um <iframe>?

Tags: css, iframe

Andei testando recentemente os pseudo-elementos [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::after) e [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::before) em um elemento `<iframe>` e como resultado não aconteceu absolutamente nada que é o caso do exemplo abaixo usando o `::after`:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    p, iframe {
      position: relative;
    }

    p::after, iframe::after {
      content: "Este conteúdo está sobrepondo o de baixo";
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      background: black;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      color: white;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Um parágrafo qualquer</p>
  <iframe src="https://ledevwd.github.io/testing/"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

No *Devtools* do navegador é possível visualizar que o `::after` foi criado, porém o estilo definido no CSS não foi aplicado ao `<iframe>`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque isso está acontecendo? Visto que até mesmo páginas internas que estão na mesma origem do site incorporadas no `<iframe>` os pseudo-elementos `::after` ou `::before` não funcionam.

Comment: Até onde sei – e posso estar enganado –, não dá para utilizar esses pseudo-elementos em elementos cujo conteúdo é ["substituído"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), como no caso de iframe, img, entre outros.

Comment: @bfavaretto, mas teria algum motivo lógico para não funcionar? Tipo usabilidade,  segurança e etc? O máximo que eu consegui fazer não aplicando estilos diretamente no `<iframe>`, mas sim, indiretamente em um elemento pai que contém o `<iframe>`, porém isso daria basicamente no mesmo só que simularia uma estilização no `<iframe>`.

Comment: Pra começo de conversa, o conteúdo do iframe não é afetado pelo CSS da página onde o iframe está. Essa sua expectativa de partida já está furada. O motivo não tem nada a ver com segurança etc, tem a ver com como funciona esse conceito de "replaced element" na renderização de páginas web.

Comment: @bfavaretto, mas eu me refiro ao próprio `<iframe>` e não o conteúdo de dentro dele. E sim é possível alterar o `<iframe>` com determinadas propriedades e seletores na própria página que o `<iframe>` está, porém `::after` e `::before` é uma das que não funcionam, mas como você falou e é o mais provável pode ser o "como funciona".

Comment: [*Descendants of iframe elements represent nothing. (In legacy user agents that do not support iframe elements, the contents would be parsed as markup that could act as fallback content.)*](https://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/Overview.html#embedded-content-0)

Answer (score 1):

**1º** Não dá pra alterar nada nas Páginas de um iframe

**2º** ***"Este conteúdo está sobrepondo o de baixo"***

ele está sobrepondo o ***"Um parágrafo qualquer"***
porque você alterou a posição de todos os parágrafos da Pág.
para `position:relative;`. obviavimente os filhos destes parágrafos, no caso as pseudo-classes, vão sobrepor mesmo o elemento pai, pois um elemento filho com `position:absolute;`, cujo elemento pai tem `position:relative;`
estes filhos ficarão por cima do elemento pai, isso é regra básica de css.

**3º** o que você viu no devtools, relacionado a pseudo-classe
do `<iframe>` nada mais era do que apenas as propriedades que você
lançou, mas isso não quer dizer que a pseudo-classe foi criada.
eu posso definir no css de uma página, varias propriedades para uma tag `<img>` sem sequer tê-la na página. as propriedades lançadas à tag  `<img>` vão continuar a aparecer normalmente no devtools.

**4º** E respondendo sua pergunta, a tag `<iframe>` não aceita pseudo-classes.

Answer (score -3):

A princípio eu diria que você não pode modificar nada no conteúdo de um iframe da sua página principal. O máximo que você pode fazer é trabalhar no css as dimensões do iframe.
Segue aqui um link para exemplificação: https://fiodevida.com/como-definir-o-estilo-de-iframes-com-css/